# createProcess createPipeを使いやすくしたラッパークラスのようなものはないでしょうか

Tags: c, windows, winapi, visual-c++

win32apiのcreateProcessとcreatePipeを使って子プロセスとやり取りしたいと思っています。
しかしサンプルコードなどをググって調べてみても複雑すぎて理解が追いつきません。
もうギブアップしかけています。
createProcessやcreatePipeをもっと使いやすいようにラッパークラスを用意してくれている方はいらっしゃらないでしょうか。

kunifさんに教えていただいたサンプルを改造したものがこちらになります。
子プロセスで起動するプログラム名はchild.exeになります。

エラー処理などはかなり適当です。
また、子プロセスからの応答が遅いとバグってしまうようです。
WaitForSingleObjectなども試してみたのですがうまくいかず
とりあえず、私の本当に使いたかったプログラム上ではSleepでごまかしています。

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <strsafe.h>

#define BUFSIZE 4096 
 
HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Wr = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = NULL;

HANDLE g_hInputFile = NULL;
 
void CreateChildProcess(void); 
void WriteToPipe(void); 
void ReadFromPipe(void); 
void ErrorExit(PTSTR); 
 
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[]) 
{ 
   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr; 
 
   printf("\n->Start of parent execution.\n");

// Set the bInheritHandle flag so pipe handles are inherited. 
 
   saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
   saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
   saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 

// Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT. 
 
   if ( ! CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, 0) ) 
      ErrorExit(TEXT("StdoutRd CreatePipe")); 

// Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDOUT is not inherited.

   if ( ! SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) )
      ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdout SetHandleInformation")); 

// Create a pipe for the child process's STDIN. 
 
   if (! CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_IN_Rd, &g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, &saAttr, 0)) 
      ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdin CreatePipe")); 

// Ensure the write handle to the pipe for STDIN is not inherited. 
 
   if ( ! SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) )
      ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdin SetHandleInformation")); 
 
// Create the child process. 
   
   CreateChildProcess();

// Get a handle to an input file for the parent. 
// This example assumes a plain text file and uses string output to verify data flow. 
 
//   if (argc == 1) 
//    ErrorExit(TEXT("Please specify an input file.\n")); 

    /*
   g_hInputFile = CreateFile(
       argv[1], 
       GENERIC_READ, 
       0, 
       NULL, 
       OPEN_EXISTING, 
       FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY, 
       NULL); 
*/
    g_hInputFile = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    
    
   if ( g_hInputFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) 
      ErrorExit(TEXT("CreateFile")); 
 
// Write to the pipe that is the standard input for a child process. 
// Data is written to the pipe's buffers, so it is not necessary to wait
// until the child process is running before writing data.
 
    while(true)
    {
   WriteToPipe(); 
   printf( "\n->Contents of %s written to child STDIN pipe.\n", argv[1]);
 
// Read from pipe that is the standard output for child process. 
 
   printf( "\n->Contents of child process STDOUT:\n\n");
   ReadFromPipe(); 
    }
   printf("\n->End of parent execution.\n");

// The remaining open handles are cleaned up when this process terminates. 
// To avoid resource leaks in a larger application, close handles explicitly. 

   return 0; 
} 
 
void CreateChildProcess()
// Create a child process that uses the previously created pipes for STDIN and STDOUT.
{ 
   TCHAR szCmdline[]=TEXT("child");
   PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo; 
   STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
   BOOL bSuccess = FALSE; 
 
// Set up members of the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure. 
 
   ZeroMemory( &piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION) );
 
// Set up members of the STARTUPINFO structure. 
// This structure specifies the STDIN and STDOUT handles for redirection.
 
   ZeroMemory( &siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO) );
   siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO); 
   siStartInfo.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
   siStartInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
   siStartInfo.hStdInput = g_hChildStd_IN_Rd;
   siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
 
// Create the child process. 
    
   bSuccess = CreateProcess(NULL, 
      szCmdline,     // command line 
      NULL,          // process security attributes 
      NULL,          // primary thread security attributes 
      TRUE,          // handles are inherited 
      0,             // creation flags 
      NULL,          // use parent's environment 
      NULL,          // use parent's current directory 
      &siStartInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer 
      &piProcInfo);  // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION 
   
   // If an error occurs, exit the application. 
   if ( ! bSuccess ) 
      ErrorExit(TEXT("CreateProcess"));
   else 
   {
      // Close handles to the child process and its primary thread.
      // Some applications might keep these handles to monitor the status
      // of the child process, for example. 

      CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
      CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);
      
      // Close handles to the stdin and stdout pipes no longer needed by the child process.
      // If they are not explicitly closed, there is no way to recognize that the child process has ended.
      
      CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr);
      CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Rd);
   }
}
 
void WriteToPipe(void) 

// Read from a file and write its contents to the pipe for the child's STDIN.
// Stop when there is no more data. 
{ 
   DWORD dwRead, dwWritten; 
   CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
   BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
 
//   for (;;) 
 //  { 
      bSuccess = ReadFile(g_hInputFile, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
//      if ( ! bSuccess || dwRead == 0 ) break; 
      
      bSuccess = WriteFile(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, chBuf, dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
 //     if ( ! bSuccess ) break; 
 //  } 
 
// Close the pipe handle so the child process stops reading. 
 
 //  if ( ! CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr) ) 
  //    ErrorExit(TEXT("StdInWr CloseHandle")); 
} 
 
void ReadFromPipe(void) 

// Read output from the child process's pipe for STDOUT
// and write to the parent process's pipe for STDOUT. 
// Stop when there is no more data. 
{ 
   DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
   CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE]; 
   BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
   HANDLE hParentStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

//   for (;;) 
  // { 
      bSuccess = ReadFile( g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
  //    if( ! bSuccess || dwRead == 0 ) break; 

      bSuccess = WriteFile(hParentStdOut, chBuf, 
                           dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
   //   if (! bSuccess ) break; 
   //} 
} 
 
void ErrorExit(PTSTR lpszFunction) 

// Format a readable error message, display a message box, 
// and exit from the application.
{ 
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf)+lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction)+40)*sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, 
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"), 
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf); 
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
    ExitProcess(1);
}
```

Comment: 補足ですが、子プロセスの標準入力に文字列を投げてから子プロセスからの標準出力を受け取ってまた子プロセスの標準入力に文字列を投げてっていうループを実行したいです。

Comment: ラッパーではないですがサンプルはあるようです。[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output)

Comment: ありがとうございます。結構複雑ですがなんとか読んでみたいと思います。

Comment: 同じサンプルをベースに似たようなことをやろうとしていると思われる記事がこちら。[Two way parent child communication in windows with c++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32501274/9014308)

Comment: とりあえず一個目のコメントのリンクのサンプルは動きました。ただ、これだと通信が一回きりなのでこれを対話型にしなければなりません。もうしばらく考えてみます。。

Comment: できました。kunifさんのサンプルを参考にしました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: どんな風に改造すると出来たかを自己回答にすると情報共有出来て良いので是非お願いします。

Answer (score 0):

希望を満たすかはわかりませんが、CRT; Cランタイムライブラリに含まれている[プロセス制御と環境制御](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/c-runtime-library/process-and-environment-control?view=msvc-170)が用意されています。

- `system`や`_spawn*`などのプロセス起動
- `_pipe`や`_popen`などのパイプ

があり、これらは`_`の付かない同名の関数がUNIX系OSにもあり、似たような動きをします。